# Suspending one virtual desktop in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, virtual-desktop

I usually work at the same computer as I watch tv series, play videogames... I like using separate virtual desktops for these things to mantain order, as my browser instances tend to have more than ten tabs, and I open several different programs.

Once I have done with the work for the day, I would like to "suspend" the "work desktop" in order to save resources (to play a videogame, for example) and to not lose information (If you close a window of Opera browser and there is another one you lose the tabs of this window) and in order to keep all the programs frozen to continue working the next day.

Is this possible? I would prefer to use the Windows built in desktops but if this is not possible I don't mind third party aplications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe windows 10 virtual desktops allow for suspending desktops, however a program like VirtualBox allows for saving a virtual machines state so you can come back to it where you paused it later on though.

Comment: I would prefer a more lightweight option.

Comment: I am not sure there is a more light weight option when it comes to windows. Unless you use a third party software for virtual desktops which I am not aware of any that do what you are asking.